# BufferedWriter doesn't write all the data on a BluetoothSocket

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, bufferedwriter

I wrote a method to write in a BluetoothSocket buit it doesn't writes everything.

```
public static String BluetoothPrint(String cFichero, String cMAC){

String cFail = "Fail";

try{
    BluetoothAdapter oBluetoothAdapter  = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice  oDispositivo       = oBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(cMAC);

    cFail = "Fail socket";      

    Method          oMethod = oDispositivo.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
    BluetoothSocket     oSocket = (BluetoothSocket) oMethod.invoke(oDispositivo, Integer.valueOf(1));
    oSocket.connect();

    cFail = "Fail getOutput";

    BufferedWriter oStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(oSocket.getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));

    cFail = "Fail write";

    oStream.flush();
    oStream.write(cFichero,0,cFichero.length());
    oStream.close();

    oSocket.close()

}catch(Exception e){return cFail;}
return "ok";}
```

There is any size limit on this method? The file I've trying to write sizes 5,37KB

Comment: How do you know that not everything is written?  Also, you should close things in a finally block so you don't leak streams or sockets if there is an exception.

Comment: @Gray Because I get the info in the Socket.

Comment: What exception was thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the answer. The problem was the buffer of the socket 'oSocket'.
I rewrited my method to send the data in chunks and wait.

```
public static String BluetoothPrint(String cFichero, String cMAC)
{
String cFail = "Fail";
byte oByte;
byte[] msg = cFichero.getBytes();

try{
    BluetoothAdapter oBluetoothAdapter  = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice  oDispositivo       = oBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(cMAC);

    cFail = "Fail socket";      

    Method oMethod = oDispositivo.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",new Class[] { int.class });
    BluetoothSocket oSocket = (BluetoothSocket) oMethod.invoke(oDispositivo, Integer.valueOf(1));
    oSocket.connect();

    cFail = "Fail getOutput";

    BufferedOutputStream(oSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedOutputStream btoutputstream = new BufferedOutputStream(oSocket.getOutputStream(),512);

    cFail = "Fail write";

    int off = 0;

    while(off < msg.length){

        btoutputstream.write(msg,off,64);
        btoutputstream.flush();

        Thread.sleep(600);

        off += 64; 
    }

    btoutputstream.close();
    oSocket.close();

}catch(Exception e){return cFail;}

return "ok";
}
```

Comment: The problem was the buffer of the socket how? There's no reason why these changes should fix anything. What else changed?

Comment: The socket belong to a printer. That printer has a buffer of only 1,5Kb. With this method my device wait enough to let the printer empty his buffer.